# PostgreSQL 9.1 runs into inconsistent data, but pg_dump corrects the problem?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, corruption

We are running a **PostgreSQL 9.1.20** with a database of about 50GB.

1. All things works fine.
2. After some days strange unexpected values appear in numeric columns,  like negative or bigger values in unexpected places.
3. The strange part: if we run a `pg_dump` of the same "corrupted" database, and then restore it (in the same server), the data becomes all ok. Now the same queries return different values!

Why does the database dump have different values when we are taking the dump exactly from the "corrupted" database? (The dump has corrected values from our perception!)

Can this be related to some kind of broken transaction or hard drive trouble? Note that restarting the database does not solve the problem.

What can be the cause behind this problem?

As requested in the comments some examples of data:

```
    #psql 
    \c base
    select * from salXXXX where sal_id=2323; 
    sal_id | sal_XXXX | XXXXXX | XXXXXX | XXXXX | XXXXX | XXXXX 
--------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------------+------------
   2323 |     -30.43 | 42586501      |                  6 |         13 | f                     | 

    \quit
    pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 --user=postgres >backup.sql
    psql 
    drop database base;
    create database base;
    \c base 
    \i backup.sql
    (no errors found here) 
    select * from salXXXX where sal_id=2323; 
    sal_id | sal_XXXX | XXXXXX | XXXXXX | XXXXX | XXXXX | XXXXX 
--------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------------+------------
   2323 |    245.43 | 42586501      |                  6 |         13 | f                     |
```

It is hard to emulate it, rarely occurs, but when it occurs we just do a dump, it is a ridiculous solution, but it works.

This is just an example, many more wrong values start to appear, even if we reprocess the data. But if the database is dumped and restored, values are in the expected range again.

Comment: Neither of the problems you listed can cause this.  You should show the data that you expect to be there, the query you use, indexes that might be involved, the actual output and the exact PostgreSQL version.  At least.

Comment: Dezso i am thinking about transactions, because it is very like the transaction isolation is interfering on the whole system, what is not permited.. but some bug is causing it.

Comment: I'd rather look into devs testing on this DB or similar.  Turn on logging all statements, and the next time this occurs, find the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be **index corruption** - assuming you have an index on `sal_id`.

If so, [`REINDEX TABLE salXXXX;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html) (or just `REINDEX INDEX index_name` would do the same trick as your dump/restore cycle, which also recreates all indexes from scratch.

[The manual advises:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

> Note that while this method does not require locking out other
>   clients, it might still be wise to prevent other users from connecting
>   to the damaged database until repairs have been completed.

Generally, consider upgrading to a current version of Postgres. [Version 9.1 has just reached its EOL in Sept. 2016.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) There have been many related updates since, might very well fix the problem for good.

Comment: @777Anon: None of what you report is "normal". Index corruption should not occur in the first place. If you have concurrent access to the db, locks on the table might slow the `REINDEX` process down. You might want to take a write lock on the table first or drop and recreate the index instead (`CREATE INDEX` also locks the table).

Comment: I runned the reindex. It causes a strange behavior, the values changed with reindex what probably means that you are in the right way, but it changes not to the correct value, but a random value, i am reindexing the entire database now. The interesting thing is that a bigger database (with the same structure) run in the same postgresql instance without any trouble.

Comment: @777Anon: You did take a backup, right? Normally `REINDEX` is uncritical, but with strange things happening, it's best to have a backup ...

Comment: Dont worry this is not in production anymore! We have a lot of backups (dumps) or in a funny way: auto-corrected dumps.  The production is just stopped (waiting) for this database.

Comment: Friend thank you. I changed the memory sticks from the server, and it is looking like pretty good now, but i am still testing it. Thanks!

Comment: @777Anon: Good to hear. Faulty memory is often behind corrupted indexes and odd behavior.